# When do Pokemon outbreaks change routes?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I was trying to find out when the swarming on a Pokemon outbreak change to another route, but I could only find this information about "soft-reset". But nothing about the time to reset while playing.

[Bulbapedia:](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_outbreak#Black_and_White)

"The gates in Unova have a monitor inside that will alert the player where an outbreak is taking place. During winter, the monitor may occasionally not report on outbreaks, which is due to parts of Route 8, where Croagunk can be found, becoming frozen during Winter and not allowing the Pokémon to be caught there. All have the level range of 15-55.
Unlike previous games, the Pokémon outbreaks can be manipulated by soft resetting the game: turning the console off without saving the game beforehand. When the game is restarted, there will be a different Pokémon swarming."

In Black-White (gen V) works like [Gen II](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_outbreak#Generation_II) ?

"Pokémon outbreaks originated in Generation II. In that generation, if the player registered a certain Trainer in the Pokégear, that Trainer would occassionally call to tell the player that he saw or heard about a large number of Pokémon in a certain area; **for the next 30 minutes** after such a call (in real time, not play time), the swarming Pokémon would appear in the given area with much greater frequency than the usual 1%."

Comment: It sounds like this lasts the entire play session until you reset the game. Is there any evidence to suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Discussion page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:Pok%C3%A9mon_outbreak#Save.2FReset_Question) of Pokemon Outbreaks (in regards to how to reset the swarm):

> Actually, any sort of reset will work, **provided you have not already saved on that date**. I've taken advantage of this multiple times. If you save after the date changes, though, even if you haven't yet inspected a board, the swarming Pokémon will be set in stone. --AndyPKMN (talk) 14:16, 7 May 2011 (UTC)

Pokemon outbreaks are set by the *date*, lasting that whole date only *after* the swarm for that day has been set and saved to the cart.

Comment: The not saving trick doesn't seem to work for me... I had an outbreak on Route 6, set the DS clock to 12:59 and got back in game, watched the day change, and the outbreak was then Route 8. I wanted Route 12 or 15 so I soft reset without saving but when i got back on it was back to Route 6. I've tried this multiple times, each time the first clock change will give me a new outbreak and then every soft reset after just gives me Route 6 again. This is in Black 2 by the way, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have to, well... Wait it out. It's so annoying waiting for the guy at Twist Mountain to give me a Shield Fossil and waiting for Route 10's outbreak, for some Tyrouge.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing time to after 6:00 PM. The manager on Rt.17 has a blank screen so don't bother. There isn't any outbreaks at Rt.17 because it's just water.

Comment: You can find Pokemons in the water, what is the point about your comment "There isn't any outbreaks at Rt.17 because it's just water."? And yes, there is no outbreaks on R.17 here is the [link](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Outbreak#Black_and_White)